# How to debug very slow CREATE DATABASE statement in postgres 12

Tags: postgresql

All other database operation are running at full speed.
This on several hosts and Ubuntu 22.04 LXC containers on that we have been using otherwise very successfully for a couple of years.
Turning fsync off doesnt make any difference.
diskio and processor utilisation is minimal so that isnt it.
I tried logging with debug level 3 but could not find anything.
Listing the various process logs in sql and linux just shows processes quietly waiting for something but I cannot find out what exactly.
The template1 database is virtually empty.

```
2022-10-31 14:10:02.743 UTC [1086558] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 17249.532 ms  statement: CREATE DATABASE xo_dict WITH ENCODING='UTF8' 
2022-10-31 14:10:11.569 UTC [1090734] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 8010.033 ms  statement: DROP DATABASE exodus2b
2022-10-31 14:10:13.359 UTC [1086558] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 9596.890 ms  statement: DROP DATABASE xo_dict
2022-10-31 14:10:15.076 UTC [1090734] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 3491.147 ms  statement: DROP DATABASE exodus3b
2022-10-31 14:10:32.291 UTC [1093962] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 15510.507 ms  statement: CREATE DATABASE exodus2b WITH ENCODING='UTF8' 
2022-10-31 14:10:52.174 UTC [1093962] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 19864.597 ms  statement: CREATE DATABASE exodus3b WITH ENCODING='UTF8'  TEMPLATE exodus2b
2022-10-31 14:10:52.932 UTC [1093962] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 740.990 ms  statement: DROP DATABASE exodus2b
2022-10-31 14:10:55.849 UTC [1093962] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 2129.943 ms  statement: DROP DATABASE exodus3b
2022-10-31 14:11:13.755 UTC [1102944] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 17885.511 ms  statement: CREATE DATABASE exodus2b WITH ENCODING='UTF8' 
2022-10-31 14:11:43.537 UTC [1102944] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 29769.648 ms  statement: CREATE DATABASE exodus3b WITH ENCODING='UTF8' 
2022-10-31 14:21:33.410 UTC [1247048] exodus@exodus LOG:  duration: 15115.960 ms  statement: CREATE DATABASE xo_dict WITH ENCODING='UTF8'
```

Comment: Check event triggers, maybe you have event triggers for `create` clauses. For more information : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createeventtrigger.html

Comment: No event triggers have been created.

Comment: You can check if `template0` contains a lot of data. Each time you create a new database that will be copied.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You mean `template1`.

Comment: Perhaps your disk is just very slow. `CREATE DATABASE` copies files around.

Comment: diskio (according to iotop) and processor utilisation is minimal so that isnt it.